# Is there any difference between Matrix.setRotateM and Matrix.rotateM

Tags: android, matrix, opengl-es-2.0

There are two methods to rotate matrices in android.opengl.Matrix class, they are:

1. `static void rotateM (float[] m, int mOffset, float a, float x, float y, float z)`
   Rotates matrix m in place by angle a (in degrees) around the axis (x, y, z)
2. `static void setRotateM(float[] rm, int rmOffset, float a, float x, float y, float z)`
   Rotates matrix m by angle a (in degrees) around the axis (x, y, z)

[Here is the original ducumentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/Matrix.html)

These methods act a bit different, but I don't understand the exact difference. Coul you explain this to me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say matrix R is rotation matrix around (x,y,z) axis by angle a, then rotateM method modifies existing matrix m like this: `m = R * m`, but setRotateM overwrites it: `m = R`.